# numpy loadtxt single line/row as list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a data file with only one line like:

```
 1.2  2.1  3.2
```

I used numpy version 1.3.0 loadtxt to load it

```
 a,b,c = loadtxt("data.dat", usecols(0,1,2), unpack=True)
```

The output was a float instead of array like

```
 a = 1.2
```

I expect it would be:

```
 a = array([1.2])
```

If i read a file with multiple lines, it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way without using reshape is, to explicitly typecast the list

```
 a,b,c = loadtxt("data.dat", usecols(0,1,2), unpack=True)
 a,b,c = (a,b,c) if usi.shape else ([a], [b], [c])
```

This works faster than the reshape!

Answer (score 5):

Simply use the numpy's inbuit loadtxt parameter ndmin.

```
a,b,c=np.loadtxt('data.dat',ndmin=2,unpack=True)
```

output

```
a=[1.2]
```

Comment: In a case like this you should submit an edit to the accepted answer, and clearly state that this is an update some 6 years later. Note that `ndim` was implemented in numpy 1.6 which is not the version used by OP.

Comment: this ndmin parameter saved my life, this is what I was looking for, for this kind of problem

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is that when you load the array you obtain a monodimensional one. When you unpack it, it obtain a set of numbers, i.e. array without dimension. This is because when you unpack an array, it decrease it's number of dimension by one. starting with a monodimensional array, it boil down to a simple number.

If you test for the type of a, it is not a float, but a numpy.float, that has all the properties of an array but a void tuple as shape. So it is an array, just is not represented as one.

If what you need is a monodimensional array with just one element, the simplest way is to reshape your array before unpacking it:

```
#note the reshape function to transform the shape
a,b,c = loadtxt("text.txt").reshape((-1,1))
```

This gives you the expected result. What is happening is that whe reshaped it into a bidimensional array, so that when you unpack it, the number of dimensions go down to one.

#### EDIT:

If you need it to work normally for multidimensional array and to keep one-dimensional when you read onedimensional array, I thik that the best way is to read normally with loadtxt and reshape you arrays in a second phase, converting them to monodimensional if they are pure numbers

```
a,b,c = loadtxt("text.txt",unpack=True)
for e in [a,b,c]
    e.reshape(e.shape if e.shape else (-1,))
```

Comment: This gives me an error if i use it for the data files, with multiple lines

Comment: you just have to adjust the reshape for your data. But of you have a multidimensional matrix you should have no problem of non-dimensional array, right? maybe you should extend your question with more specification...

Comment: As, I have mentioned in the question, without reshape it's working for files with multiple lines. If i use reshape it's only working for the files with single line. I need a generic command, such that it reads both single line files and multiple line files and return the output as an array.