# numpy.loadtxt for one and more input lines

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have a datafile, which might be one or more rows. I read it using `numpy.loadtxt`. This has the feature that it makes my single row data a scalar. This is problematic, because I want to use a loop after read in. See the below example

```
$ cat file1
1
$ cat file2
1
2
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
$ python 
$ python temp.py 
1.0
2.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 9, in <module>
    for x in data1:
TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array
```

Code

```
import numpy

data1=numpy.loadtxt ( 'file1', unpack=True )
data2=numpy.loadtxt ( 'file2', unpack=True )

for x in data2:
    print x

for x in data1:
    print x
```

I also tried the solution of the related question: [numpy loadtxt single line/row as list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528053/numpy-loadtxt-single-line-row-as-list) But I don't get it to work

I added

```
data1 = data1 if usi.shape else [data1]
```

However,

```
$ python temp.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 7, in <module>
    data1 = data1 if usi.shape else [data1]
NameError: name 'usi' is not defined
```

I also tried `import usi`, but this is not installed on my system, and it seems a bit overdone for such a simple task.

What am I doing wrong? I feel the solution is simple, but I couldn't find hints at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Comment: So how do you want it? I've been using np.loadtxt to read in .csv's, and as such have been using data_array=('filename', delimiter=','), which gives me a numpy array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
data1=numpy.loadtxt ( 'file1', unpack=True, ndmin = 1)
```

Comment: This solution works for me, therefore accepted! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could call [`np.atleast_1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_1d.html) to promote it beyond a 0-d object:

```
>>> np.loadtxt("file1.txt")
array(1.0)
>>> np.atleast_1d(np.loadtxt("file1.txt"))
array([ 1.])
```

which you can safely apply to the second array as well, as it won't do anything:

```
>>> np.loadtxt("file2.txt")
array([ 2.,  3.])
>>> np.atleast_1d(np.loadtxt("file2.txt"))
array([ 2.,  3.])
```

See also `np.atleast_2d`.

Comment: Thanks, your solution works. I accepted the other solution, because it is short (function call less)