# Reading Single Line CSV using numpy.genfromtxt

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I am using the following script to read a file from standard input using numpy.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import sys

data = np.genfromtxt(sys.stdin, delimiter=",")
print data.shape
print data
```

This works correctly for files that have more than 1 line. But fails to work for this file:

```
1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1
```

I am running it like this

```
$ cat input-file.txt | ./test.py
```

The output is as follows:

```
(9,)
[ 1.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  1.  1.  1.]
```

It should have shape (,9). Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [numpy loadtxt single line/row as list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528053/numpy-loadtxt-single-line-row-as-list)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Force it into a 2-dimensional array:

```
data = np.genfromtxt(sys.stdin, delimiter=",")
if len(data.shape) == 1:
    data = np.array([data])
```